# regex to match everything after second underscore

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

i have this array

`var collUnlocked = ['GRAVEL_1', 'GRAVEL_3', 'GRAVEL_2', 'GRAVEL_5', 'GRAVEL_4', 'GRAVEL_10', 'GRAVEL_-1', 'LOG:3_1', 'LOG:3_-1', 'LOG:3_3', 'LOG:3_4', 'LOG_2_6', 'LOG_2_2', 'LOG_2_3', 'LOG_2_-1']`

i want to get the name (ex. LOG_2), and the last number, (ex. -1)

example:
['LOG:3_4', 'GRAVEL_-1', 'LOG_2_-1']

turns into -> [['LOG:3','4'], ['GRAVEL', '-1'], ['LOG_2', '-1']]

edit: im using this code to get the name, but i cant get the last number

```
collName = x.match('(.*\_)')[0];
collName = collName.slice(0, -1);
```

full code rn:

```
function testingAll() {
  var collUnlocked = ['GRAVEL_1', 'GRAVEL_3', 'GRAVEL_2', 'GRAVEL_5', 'GRAVEL_4', 'GRAVEL_10', 'GRAVEL_-1', 'LOG:3_1', 'LOG:3_-1', 'LOG:3_3', 'LOG:3_4', 'LOG_2_6', 'LOG_2_2', 'LOG_2_3', 'LOG_2_-1']

  getCollLevelssss(collUnlocked);
}

function getCollLevelssss(collUnlocked) {
  var collName;
  var collLevel;

  collUnlocked.forEach(x => {
    collName = x.match('(.*\_)')[0];
    collName = collName.slice(0, -1);

    collLevel = x.match(''); //need regex right here

    console.log(x + ' | ' + collName + ' = ' + collLevel);
  });
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected value. When you use `var collUnlocked = ['GRAVEL_1', 'GRAVEL_3', 'GRAVEL_2', 'GRAVEL_5', 'GRAVEL_4', 'GRAVEL_10', 'GRAVEL_-1', 'LOG:3_1', 'LOG:3_-1', 'LOG:3_3', 'LOG:3_4', 'LOG_2_6', 'LOG_2_2', 'LOG_2_3', 'LOG_2_-1']`, can I ask you about your expected value?

Comment: the expected value is the name + the number after last underscore _
i will do this for each element, in the fist case the expected is
['GRAVEL', 1]
 in the 'LOG_2_-1' situation, the expected is ['LOG_2', '-1']

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script using `split()`. Could you please confirm it? If that was not your expected direction, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your goal, how about the following approach? This sample script uses `split()`.

#### Sample script:

```js
var collUnlocked = ['GRAVEL_1', 'GRAVEL_3', 'GRAVEL_2', 'GRAVEL_5', 'GRAVEL_4', 'GRAVEL_10', 'GRAVEL_-1', 'LOG:3_1', 'LOG:3_-1', 'LOG:3_3', 'LOG:3_4', 'LOG_2_6', 'LOG_2_2', 'LOG_2_3', 'LOG_2_-1']
var res = collUnlocked.map(e => {
  var temp = e.split("_");
  var last = temp.pop();
  return [temp.join("_"), last];
});
console.log(res)
```

- When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

  ```
    [ 
      [ 'GRAVEL', '1' ],
      [ 'GRAVEL', '3' ],
      [ 'GRAVEL', '2' ],
      [ 'GRAVEL', '5' ],
      [ 'GRAVEL', '4' ],
      [ 'GRAVEL', '10' ],
      [ 'GRAVEL', '-1' ],
      [ 'LOG:3', '1' ],
      [ 'LOG:3', '-1' ],
      [ 'LOG:3', '3' ],
      [ 'LOG:3', '4' ],
      [ 'LOG_2', '6' ],
      [ 'LOG_2', '2' ],
      [ 'LOG_2', '3' ],
      [ 'LOG_2', '-1' ]
    ]
  ```

#### Reference:

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 0):

#### Split and reassemble

```
function myfunk() {
  let a = ['GRAVEL_1', 'GRAVEL_3', 'GRAVEL_2', 'GRAVEL_5', 'GRAVEL_4', 'GRAVEL_10', 'GRAVEL_-1', 'LOG:3_1', 'LOG:3_-1', 'LOG:3_3', 'LOG:3_4', 'LOG_2_6', 'LOG_2_2', 'LOG_2_3', 'LOG_2_-1'];
  let b = a.reduce((a,c) => {
    let t = c.split('_');
    if(t.length == 2) {
      a.arr.push(`${t[0]},${t[1]}`);
    } else if(t.length == 3) {
      a.arr.push(`${t[0]}_${t[1]},${t[2]}`);
    }
    return a;
  },{arr:[]}).arr;
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(b));
}

Execution log
7:10:50 PM  Notice  Execution started
7:10:50 PM  Info    ["GRAVEL,1","GRAVEL,3","GRAVEL,2","GRAVEL,5","GRAVEL,4","GRAVEL,10","GRAVEL,-1","LOG:3,1","LOG:3,-1","LOG:3,3","LOG:3,4","LOG_2,6","LOG_2,2","LOG_2,3","LOG_2,-1"]
7:10:51 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split with a [negative look ahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions):

```js
const collUnlocked = ['GRAVEL_1', 'GRAVEL_3', 'GRAVEL_2', 'GRAVEL_5', 'GRAVEL_4', 'GRAVEL_10', 'GRAVEL_-1', 'LOG:3_1', 'LOG:3_-1', 'LOG:3_3', 'LOG:3_4', 'LOG_2_6', 'LOG_2_2', 'LOG_2_3', 'LOG_2_-1']
const res = collUnlocked.map(e => e.split(/_(?!.*_.*)/));
console.log(res)
```

`/_(?!.*_.*)` - `_` not followed by any `.*_.*`( any characters surrounding `_`)